# Simple way to read data from html file with my app?

Tags: android, html, file

I'm developing an app that should be able to transfer simple data between devices.

So first step is to send some data from my app on Device 1 to Device 2. I'm using the code below:

```
    Button btnShare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
    btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Name:"+oldName+",Surname:"+oldName);
            startActivity(sendIntent);

        }
    });
```

After the button click Android share menu appears and I select Bluetooth option. I use it to send data to Device 2 and it gets there as file with extension ".html".

Now I would like to open that file and use data stored inside in my app on second device.
I click on file in my Bluetooth folder and I choose my app from menu with suggested apps to use with html files.

My app on second device starts but I can't get data from the file.

What is the most simple way to get data with my app from that file?
Should I use ACTION_VIEW?

Answer (score 1):

In the activity that is opened you need to get the data via the Intent object

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    String filename = null;
    if (uri!=null)
        filename = uri.getPath();
```

Comment: Thank you i made a progress. Could you tell me how can i retrieve information from putExtra i used in code above?